# points not plotting in plot function

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot points on certain coordinates on a raster layer.

```
> head(coords_df)
     x    y
1 66.5 66.5
2 67.0 66.5
3 67.5 66.5
4 68.0 66.5
5 68.5 66.5
6 69.0 66.5
```

Im trying to plot using the following

```
plot(CNRM_1)
points(coords_df, pch=16)
```

the raster is plotting but not the points. any help  on where to fix this?

```
   > dput(head(CNRM_1))
structure(c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000796599906001783, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.000837936005501152, 0.000871552319509912, 
0.00100709419004943, 0, 0, 0.0012105632950364, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00103714216752641, 
0.00104333072151312, 0.000794459549629719, 0.00198828994745526, 
0.00232027342913862, 0.00152433704387084, 0.00145669475130489, 
0, 0, 0, 0.00106764166637498, 0.00133117261345192, 0.000751185736039872, 
0.00205181592210355, 0.00235624992234934, 0.00160364560215041, 
0.00225981611592611, 0, 0, 0, 0.00094873888615985, 0.00159345054110917, 
0.000750502129892894, 0.00166613986487262, 0.00245039132047496, 
0.00204705133350925, 0.00264872849452662, 0, 0, 0, 0.000704677797913744, 
0.00158751407612522, 0.00105819696412664, 0.00112746366228874, 
0.00220263084576204, 0.00300220982410644, 0.00268456275374276, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00112959733971154, 0.00153415586525737, 0.000503537889893361, 
0.000948829835912542, 0.00221998566976762, 0.0031083088899198
), dim = c(10L, 20L), dimnames = list(c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
"6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20")))

> dput(head(coords_df))
structure(list(x = c(66.5, 67, 67.5, 68, 68.5, 69), y = c(66.5, 
66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5, 66.5)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how the plot is supposed to look like for CNRM_1, maybe try *image*, then add *points*:

```
image(CNRM_1)

pp <- data.frame(x = c(0, 0.6), y = c(0.4, 0.8))
points(pp, pch = 16)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The reason the `points` from `coords_df` dont show up is because the x- and y-axes are different between `CRNM_1` and `coords_df`.

I agree that it's difficult to see what you want the final plot to look like and `image` is likely the way to go. However, since you used `plot(CNRM_1)` in your original approach, to add the points from `coords_df` you would need to add a new plot using `par(new = TRUE)`

```
plot(CNRM_1)
par(new = TRUE)
plot(coords_df, pch = 16, 
     axes = FALSE, 
     ylab = "", xlab = "")
```

[image]